# Internal Sever Error while trying to access php extensions on my site

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Now this site (removed) was running well until few hours ago when I tried importing demo content for my wordpress template. I got the "fatal error maximum memory exceeded" thing and decided to tweak the .htaccess file: That was when my travails began. I've tried all possible solutions ranging from deleting the whole site plus database and what not?

So, I decided to test if this error is extension related, so I uploaded an html file and tried accessing it...Voila! it opened! I tried other file extensions (css,jpg etc) everything opened except files ending with the extension ".php". What do you think could be responsible for this?

Note: I've tried increasing the php memory limit by creating a php.ini file, nothing changed.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after messing around with the site's FTP, I realised that the permission of the folders (including public_html) has been mysteriously set to 0777. Changing them to 0755 fixed my problem.